# Trying to Find Minimum Output Capacitance

Tags: capacitor, lipo

I am trying to choose an output capacitor for the TPS6107 boost converter.
My circuit will resemble the example from the datasheet.

Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/product/TPS61070/datasheet/abstract#SLVS5107171
Equations Used: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf

I need to find the minimum output capacitance so I can select my capacitor.

I am using equation 12, on page 5, from the Equations Used link: 
Csub(out,min) = (Isub(out,max) x D)/ (fsub(s) x Delta Vsub(out))

I had to solve for the output voltage ripple, Delta Vsub(out), and the inductor ripple current, delta Isub(L), as well.

I have provided my calculations below, but I think my answer is wrong. I think i may have made a mistake with my units but i'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes a couple tiny misteaks ;)  1.2e6 Hz not 12000kHz also unit multipliers [k*u=m]  or simply

1.2e6 [Hz] *4.7e-6 [H] = 5.64 not 56,400